# Race Condition on Queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, race-condition

The below code handles a socket message coming in with a 2 parameters. It puts information into a queue and is processed on another thread.  My question is if 2 messages come in right after the other and are then dequeued and sent to the method ProcessData, is there a race condition on ProcessData?

```
private void DataIn(long Code, string Message)
{
  if (!Started)
  {
    if (DataInQueue == null)
      DataInQueue = new Queue();
    DataInThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProcedure));
    DataInThreadEnding = false;
    DataInThread.IsBackground = true;
    DataInThread.Start();
    Started = true;
  }
  DataInQueue.Enqueue(new cDataIn(Code, Message));
}

private void ThreadProcedure()
{
   while (!ProgramEnding)
   {
     Queue mySyncdQ = Queue.Synchronized(DataInQueue);
     if (mySyncdQ != null && mySyncdQ.Count > 0)
     {
        cDataIn data = null;
        // Creates a synchronized wrapper around the Queue. 
        if (mySyncdQ.Count > 0)
          data = (cDataIn)mySyncdQ.Dequeue();

        ProcessData(data);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE

Queue is not used in a thread-safe manner in your code... the code you show is not enough to be sure whether there is a race condition but with the `ConcurrentQueue` you get a better performance... and in the ThreadProcedure you can have calling ProcessData with null and as far as I can tell to be on the safe side ProcessData should be reentrant for all this to work...

Use a [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) - that avoids some possible problems... and check out [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) which is designed for thread-safe Producer/Consumer scenarios... both work mostly lock-free and are really fast...

Comment: Are you saying that there is a problem?

Comment: the docs for the Queue class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=VS.100).aspx) has a paragraph about thread safety at the bottom that states instance members are not TS. I haven't looked at the implementation to see what coud go but you can check yourself by spinning up two threads. One pumps in sequential messages (1, 2, 3,.. ) and the other reads them. You'll probably get an exception or gaps/doubles (1, 2, 2, 4, 5, ...).

Comment: +1 for BlockingCollection, that is the class to use in P-C scenarios like jon describes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think this can even leave your Queue in an inconstistant state. You should use the <del>[Concurrent Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)</del> [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) that ships with .Net 4. It's threadsafe out of the box and optimzed.

Regards Gert-Jan

Comment: Why do you say there is a problem with the queue? I was more worried that the ProcessData was getting called in quick succession and the second thread might overtake the first

Comment: @Jon, the memory leak most likely won't affect you.

Comment: well you could try yourself by making a testbench like I suggest in the answer from Yahia. It depends on the internal implementation of Queue. It may use an array under the hood that needs to be copied, and then you might leave it in an inconstistent state when you do that twice at the same time. I wouldn;t risk that..

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not thread safe. Notice this in [the documentation for `Queue.Synchronized()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized.aspx):

> To guarantee the thread safety of the `Queue`, all operations must be done through this wrapper only.

You're using the queue directly, so the code is not thread-safe. To fix this, always use just the returned wrapper, as the documentation says.

Or, if you're under .Net 4, use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

If you wanted to use generic queue on an previous version of .Net, you would could use `Queue<T>` and always access it in a `lock`.

Comment: So I need to call the synchronize when I Enqueue AND Dequeue?

Comment: That's, what the documentation says, doesn't it?

Comment: Doesnt actually say about Enqueuing and Dequeuing

Comment: Enqueue and Dequeue are operations, so it does say that about them.